# How do i fix 0xc000007b error

Tags: windows-7, windows

When i launch some programs i get this error i am using windows 7 32-bit it is a fresh install. Just with updates does any one know what i could do. I don't want to buy any software so a free way would be appreciated. I have tried looking on Google but i didn't find any thing. This is the error i got. Thanks in advance.

[image]

**EDIT:** When i say some i mean programs in general i dont want a fix for just one of them.

Comment: Please provide more information.  When you say "some" programs please provide a more specific description other than "some".  This a physical installation or within a virtual machine?

Comment: When i say some i mean programs in general i dont want a fix for just one of them.

Comment: I mean.   Do you get this error for every application or just certain applications.  Be specific...

Comment: Just some but it can be any some and they are completely diffident programs.

Comment: Are we talking about programs you have written or random programs.  What exactly is `TestOpenCV.exe`?  If you want an answer to the cause of this error I need to know in what context this error happens.  Please answer the second part of my original comment that is vital information I required.

Comment: Both programs ia have made and programs in general

Comment: Sounds like this is a Stackoverflow problem.  **You have a dll dependency problem.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google is your friend, use it.  Googling TestOpenCV and c000007b results in this link http://msoos.wordpress.com/2010/09/11/0xc000007b-error-solution/

My answer is entirely the result of the google search.

The Problem

0xc000007b error comes mainly from mixing up 32bit environment with 64bit one, that is you have an 32bit application that tries to load a 64bit dll.

I used a free portable program to do this: "[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)". After you download it you can open any PE file (exe, dll, …)